# Problem running a service to execute a c executable in a rasberry pi 4

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi

I wrote a C program that reads data from a CAN socket and sends it through an RF module (LoRa SX1262) connected via a USB cable to the Raspberry Pi. The code runs perfectly fine when I run it manually in the terminal, but when it runs as a service triggered by a path, it gives an error that it can't write to the USB port.

Error Message:
Feb 07 10:42:49 driver lora-linux-main.out[893]: ERRO writing msg failed: Bad file descriptor

path file:

```
[Unit]
Description= Path unit for USB network interface usb0

[Path]
PathExists=/sys/class/net/usb0
Unit=your_service_name.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi_user.target
```

service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Your Service Description
After=usb_trigger.path network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=fstlisboa
Group=dialout
ExecStart=/home/fstlisboa/software-13/lora/bin/lora-linux-main.out
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi_user.target
```

C code:

```
#define USB_PORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

int open_port(char *serial_port_path){
    struct termios tty;
    int serial_port_fd = 0;
    
    serial_port_fd = open(serial_port_path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY |     O_SYNC);

    if (serial_port_fd < 0) {
        perror("ERROR opening USB port");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (tcgetattr(serial_port_fd, &tty) != 0) {
        perror("ERROR configuring USB port");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, B115200);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B115200);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
    tty.c_lflag = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    if (tcsetattr(serial_port_fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        perror("ERROR configuring USB port");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return serial_port_fd;
}


void send_msg(Lora lora, char *str)
{
    char msg[strlen(str) + 4];
    int serial_port_fd = 0;
    serial_port_fd = open_port(USB_PORT);
    
    if (msg == NULL) {
        perror("ERROR memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    msg[0] = lora.dest_adress_high;
    msg[1] = lora.dest_adresss_low;
    msg[2] = lora.dest_freq;

    for (int i = 3; str[i - 3] != '\0'; i++) {
        msg[i] = str[i - 3];
    }

    if (write(serial_port_fd, (unsigned const char *)msg, strlen(str) + 4) < 0) {
        perror("ERRO writing msg failed");
        return;
    }

    close(serial_port_fd);
}

Lora lora;
int s_read = 0, number_of_msg_in_json = 0;
can_frame_filter *can_lora_array = NULL;

void *send_thread_car(void *arg) {
    char can_msg_str[CAN_MSG_LORA_SIZE] = {'\0'};
    struct can_frame frame_send;
    double elapsed_time = 0;
    bool send = false;
    int filter_pos = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        frame_send = get_can_msg_from_can_socket(s_read);
        
        can_to_module(frame_send, can_msg_str);
        send_msg(lora, can_msg_str);
        can_lora_array[filter_pos].time_last_send = time(NULL);
        usleep(TIME_BETWEEN_MSG_TO_SEND_LORA);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_can addr_read;
    pthread_t send_thread;

    create_and_config_socket(CAN_PORT, &s_read, &addr_read);
    module_config(&lora, DEST_ADRESS_LORA, DEST_FREQUENCY_LORA);

    char *json_data = open_json_get_data("/home/user/Desktop/FST/software-13/lora/src/filter_can_lora.json");
    
    if (json_data == NULL) 
    {
        perror("ERROR getting data from string");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    can_lora_array = convert_into_array(json_data, &number_of_msg_in_json);

    if (can_lora_array == NULL) 
    {
        perror("ERROR converting json data to array");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if (pthread_create(&send_thread, NULL, send_thread_car, NULL) != 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR thread creation failed: send_thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(pthread_join(send_thread, NULL) != 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR joining thread: send_thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(can_lora_array);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing both the user permissions, changing the user, and changing the group and its permissions, but it didn't work.

Comment: You should provide more details on how the file descriptors are created and managed.  You should also be clear on if the issue happens immediately or if it works and then stops working.  `bad file descriptor` is likely not due to permissions but mishandled or disposed file descriptors.  Error checks should be done when opening the file.

Comment: If you're communicating with a serial port, why are you watching for `/sys/class/net/usb0`, which is a network device? Where is the `main` function in your code, and what is the value of `serial_port_path` when `open_port` is called?

Comment: If you want the service to start when the device is connected, you probably want a [udev rule](https://superuser.com/questions/851846/how-to-write-a-systemd-service-that-depends-on-a-device-being-present/851966#851966) rather than a path unit. To reiterate what I said in my earlier comment, since you didn't respond: it's very odd that your path unit is looking for a network device while your code is communicating with a serial device.